# Restricted universal extensions and lifting of derivations

Tags: lie-algebras, restricted-lie-algebras, derivations

Let $L$ be a perfect Lie algebra. Then it is well-known that $L$ has a universal central extension $\hat{L}$ and every derivation of $L$ can be lifted to a derivation of $\hat{L}$. (See e.g. Section 2 of  https://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/neher/Papers/univ.pdf.)

Now suppose that $(\mathfrak{L},[p])$ is a restricted Lie algebra over a field of characteristic $p>0$. I remember that a derivation $D$ of $L$ is said to be restricted if $D(a^{[p]})=(\mathrm{ad} a)^{p-1}(D(a))$ for every $a\in \mathfrak{L}$. If $\mathfrak{L}$ is perfect than $\mathfrak{L}$ admits a restricted universal central extension $\hat{\mathfrak{L}}$. (See e.g. http://rmi.tsu.ge/proceedings/volumes/pdf/v121-5.pdf.)

> Is it true that every restricted derivation of $\mathfrak{L}$ can be lifted to a restricted derivation of  $\hat{\mathfrak{L}}$?

Comment: What are $x$ and $a$ in your definition of a restricted derivation?

Comment: @Paul Levy: Thank you for pointing out the typos: I just corrected them.